# AWS SNS issue while creating Topic

Tags: amazon-sns

When I try to create a AWS SNS topic, I am getting the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_FINAL_FIELDS_AS_MUTATORS"

The library details are:

1. aws-java-sdk-1.11.117
2. jackson-annotations-2.9.0.pr2
3. jackson-core-2.9.0.pr2
4. jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr2

As suggested in other posts, I tried by changing the jackson library to 2.6 also but of no use.

Comment: Are you using maven?  If so, have you tried mvn clean?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the conflicted library 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind' which is added in the library path.